# Apostol's Calculus Volume I, page 6: Proof of Identity

Tags: calculus

I'm having trouble with understanding the step where he states : 
"When we add these formulas, all the terms on the right cancel except two" What did he mean by this ? I don't understand how he went from $n^3-(n-1)^3$ to $n^3-1^3$

[The Steps in question -From the textbook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZdREm.png)

Comment: Do you mean "Tom Apostol"? He is not an apostle, I think.

Comment: Ah sorry, my bad yeah I meant Apostol

Comment: Apostol does not claim that $n^3 - (n-1)^3$ equals $n^3 -1^3$.  Rather, suppose $n=5$. If you add $5^3 - 4^3$ to $4^3 - 3^3$ you get $5^3 - 3^3$.  Now you add $3^3 - 2^3$ and you get $5^3 - 2^3$ and finally, adding $2^3 - 1^3$ you get $5^3 - 1^3$.  Of course, if you add all the left-hand sides of the equations you get something equal to $5^3 - 1^3$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you sum all the equations, the term on the right will be 
$n^3$$-(n-1)^3+(n-1)^3$$-(n-2)^3+(n-2)^3$$-(n-3)^3+(n-3)^3$$-(n-4)^3+...+3^3-2^3+2^3-1^3$
----^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^---------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^-------------------------^^^^

The pairs of terms (coming form different lines) underlined in the same way cancel each other.